# How to add msgboxs Before hta appears

Tags: vbscript, hta

How to --

Add message boxes before hta appears?

I tried adding msgboxes in

```
        Window_onload
```

But behind msgbox hta window appears.is there any possible way to pop up messages before hta windows start appearing on the screen?

Thanks stackoverflow team I got many solutions.

Comment: Why do you want to do like that ? please explain more your aim !

Comment: My Hta uses external styling sheets(css).if css not found it msgbox "Styling Components Not Found" and behind this message box a screen with wrapped text and buttons appears.so I want to load hta only if css found.

Comment: Can you put the error message in the HTA window (instead of a msgbox)? Instead of `MsgBox "error message"` use `document.body.innerhtml = "error message"`

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if hta have got a feature for it, but you could just use a wrapper. either another hta or a vbs that shows the msgbox, then opens the main hta

```
msgbox("your message before opening the hta")
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run page.hta
```

this would do it if you use vbs

Answer (score 0):

(1) **Think** before you (ask for help wrt a pipe-dream) **hack**.

(a) Except for special cases (lunar lander, pacemaker, ...) a program can assume its correct installation and integrity. The accessability of resources (e.g. some .css files) rests with your installation manual/script/test or - in a volatile enviroment - with the process/agent that invokes your .hta (cf. BLP's answer). So there is no need for that check **in** your .hta.

(b) If you use "window_onload", you know that

> load: - A user agent MUST dispatch this event when the DOM implementation
>   finishes loading the resource (such as the document) and any dependent
>   resources (such as images, style sheets, or scripts). Dependent
>   resources that fail to load MUST NOT prevent this event from firing if
>   the resource that loaded them is still accessible via the DOM. If this
>   event type is dispatched, implementations are REQUIRED to dispatch
>   this event at least on the Document node.

(said the [horse](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-load))

Why are you surprised that code in the event handler is 'too late'? Won't your aim - abort the .hta - clash with the rule "handler must be called even if some resource fails to load"?

(c) If you still want to experiment with "what happens when", use a minimal template like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>WhatWhen</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="WhatWhen">

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
MsgBox "Script started"

Sub Window_onLoad
  MsgBox "Window_onLoad"
End Sub
  </SCRIPT>

 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

and move the script block before the title.

(2) Code (if need be: hack) and **test** before you even **think** of posting an answer.

E.g.: BLP's proposal to check the existence of the resources (.css) **before** you start the .hta is sound but the implementation

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run page.hta
```

wouldn't survive a trial run.